# .NET Core API Middleware - Accessing "Endpoint.RequestDelegate.Target" properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dynamic

I have custom middleware that is called before my API endpoints. Example endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething (string id) { // does stuff }
```

`DoSomething()` should only accept `POST` requests.

If the endpoint is pinged with an *incorrect HTTP verb*, like `GET` or `DELETE`, I want to log that this happened. To do so correctly, I need to know that the `DoSomething()` endpoint *is defined as `[HttpPost]`*.

Here's my middleware's `InvokeAsync` method.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync (HttpContext context)
{
    Endpoint endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

    if (endpoint != null)
    {
        // if we get '405 not supported', we used INCORRECT HTTP VERB
        if (endpoint.DisplayName.StartsWith("405", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            dynamic target = endpoint.RequestDelegate.Target;
            string verb = target.allow; // error here
        }
    }
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that `endpoint.RequestDelegate.Target` has a property called `allow` that is set to "POST". But I cannot access that field, how do I get access to it? The above code returns the error:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'allow'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using reflection, but I'm not sure if it's cheating since according to the debugger, I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be a private field. Oh, well.

```
var allowField = endpoint.RequestDelegate.Target
     .GetType()
     .GetFields()
     .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals("allow"));

if (allowField != null)
{
     string allowedHttpCommand = (string)allowField.GetValue(endpoint.RequestDelegate.Target);
}
```